# How to have a package maintain its own keychain access

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently developing an SDK for other apps and I'd like to maintain my own keychain access within my SDK that's sandboxed away from main app that only my internal functions can access. My understanding so far is that access is primarily governed by the `application-identifier` entitlement. I thought I could package my keychain access code as an `xcframework` which would give it its own `application-identifier` which would be protected with code signing.

However, when I went to run my app accessing the keychain from framework and from main app I found their entitlements were the same.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so how can I do it?

Comment: IMO you are confusing several different things: to maintain your own portion of keychain you neither need a separate sandbox, nor the separate application-identifier. You just create your items in the way that only your SDK knows how to save and retrieve, and don't expose that access to outside world (i.e. classes that handle keychain are internal to your SDK). I.e. your SDK sets your unique `kSecAttrService`, `kSecAttrAccount` etc on saving / retrieving. The app will still "own" it. But they only can access the content if they reverse engineer your code, or the keychain...

Comment: @ohglstr I could ship a signed binary blob but this approach doesn’t guarantee any safety. Especially since those values are just strings it feels like it wouldn’t be too difficult to reverse.

Comment: Safety from whom? what specific threat are you trying to address?